# Bypass if it has null values in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am very new to Angular. Here is my function in a component that calls API and expects results but it can also result in errors.

```
 this.Service.callAPI().
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(data?.errors){
       });
```

It is failing because data and also errors can be null. It says `cannot read the property of null`. How can I fix this? I have tried `data?.errors?` but it does not work.

Comment: "It says cannot read the property of null" means that you simply can not read any property from "data" because it is null. Check the inspector what kind of response you get from the "this.Service.callAPI()" call.

Answer (score 1):

Question mark is used to check undefined or null values in html not in typescript files.

Replace your line if(data?.errors) with if(data && data.errors). 
 It should work

Hope this fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be to apply [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operator before subscribing and filter the null and undefined values.

Try this:

```
this.Service.callAPI().pipe(
  filter(data => data !== undefined && data !== null),
).subscribe(data => {
  if (data.errors) {
    // at this point, data won't be undefined or null
  }
})
```